# Avoid conctructor recall or make it right, how?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay

I have absolutely workable portlet. It is a complicated form with many popups, lazytables, tables and so on. It works fine. And want to allow it to autofill all fields and structures. I add in constructor analizing parameter from url:

```
RenderRequest renderRequest = (RenderRequest) (FacesContext .getCurrentInstance()  
                .getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("javax.portlet.request"));   
        String applicationIndex = renderRequest.getParameter("caid");
```

and initializing structures with data or by default constructors.

when I open any popup, i see them without data or their buttons doesn't react on clicking. And this in log:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.ResourceRequestImpl cannot be cast to javax.portlet.RenderRequest

it occurs at line:

`RenderRequest renderRequest = (RenderRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance).getExternalContext).getRequestMap).get"java`x.portlet.request"));

it is the first line of the bean constructor.

So the question is: how to make the constructor work correctly in this circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

You're casting a `ResourceRequest`, which, in a portal world points to a the resource lifecycle phase (e.g. Ajax), but you're casting it to a `RenderRequest`, which is tied to the render phase.

You might just want to use `PortletRequest`, which is the supertype of `ResourceRequest` as well as of `RenderRequest`.